# How to know labels of generated images in WGAN using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on medical image classification problem, and suffering from low data set problem. So want to generate images using [WGAN](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/wgan/wgan.py). In given code WGAN code example is taken of MNIST data set. after image generation it's easy to recognize digit which class they belongs too. But in medical image case, after generating images it's hard to decide generated images belongs to which category, because they saved in group from following code given:

```
def sample_images(self, epoch):
        r, c = 5, 5
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (r * c, self.latent_dim))
        gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

        # Rescale images 0 - 1
        gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5

        fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(r):
            for j in range(c):
                axs[i,j].imshow(gen_imgs[cnt, :,:,0], cmap='gray')
                axs[i,j].axis('off')
                cnt += 1
        fig.savefig("images/mnist_%d.png" % epoch)
        plt.close()
```

so what changes i have to perform to get labels of generated images.

Answer (score 1):

WGAN in the vanilla version cannot generate images conditionally. Therefore, the WGAN you have trained can only generate images without any knowledge of which class they belong to.

To be able to generate images of a particular label, check out conditonal gans. [Here's](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/gan-cgan-infogan-using-labels-to-improve-gan-8ba4de5f9c3d) a medium article to get you started.

The alternate option is to train a discriminator from the original training data and use that discriminator to help you manually classify the images.

Comment: yup , i thought the same. What i did is, i run my WGAN code 2 times. each time i only give single class. Is this correct approach?

Comment: That's an option as well. But given that you have very less training data. It would be better to maximise the gan's potential by training on the entire set.

Comment: Yup i have very less data. and i am doing training on entire set.